# Angularjs bind input text value from controller for each record depending upon label

Tags: angularjs

I have 5 textboxes with different labels for each.

My array will have many objects so depending upon the key label for each

object want to display that record value for the particular type of textbox.

Say for example

1. if first record has label as "High" then for that record textbox value of first textbox should be set to the value defined with key as "value" rest text boxes value should be empty for that particular row.
2. if second record has label as "Low" then for that record textbox value of first textbox should be set to the value defined with key as "value"  rest text boxes value should be empty for that particular row.
3. And so on

Follow the plunkr (code pasted below):
http://plnkr.co/edit/FYBXVk?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <style>
        input {
            width: 60px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="filterController">
        <div ng-repeat="x in family[0].measures" ng-init="getLabelValue(x)">
            <p>{{x.type.measureType}}</p>
            High<input type="text" ng-model="highValue" />
            Mid<input type="text" ng-model="midValue" />
            VHigh<input type="text" ng-model="vHighValue" />
            Low<input type="text" ng-model="lowValue" />
            EHigh<input type="text" ng-model="eHighValue" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the scope variable for the input field `ng-model` is not a good method. Better use `ng-modal` value as a property of `ng-repeat` object. Here is the implementation.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>
        document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
    </script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
        myApp.controller("filterController", function ($scope) {

            $scope.family = [
                    {
                    "measures": [{"type": {"label": "high","measureType": "Product Name 1"},"value": 122},
                                    {"type": {"label": "mid","measureType": "Product Name 2"},"value": 232},
                                    {"type": {"label": "vhigh","measureType": "Product Name 3"},"value": 222.5},
                                    {"type": {"label": "low","measureType": "Product Name 4"},"value": 122.5},
                                    {"type": {"label": "ehigh","measureType": "Product Name 5"},"value": 322}
                                ]
                    }
                ];


            $scope.getLabelValue = function (currentMeasure) {
                $scope.highValue = null;
                $scope.midValue = null;
                $scope.vHighValue = null;
                $scope.lowValue = null;
                $scope.eHighValue = null;
                if (currentMeasure.type.label == "high"){
                    $scope.highValue = currentMeasure.value;
                }
                else if (currentMeasure.type.label == "mid"){
                    $scope.midValue = currentMeasure.value;
                }
                else if (currentMeasure.type.label == "vhigh"){
                    $scope.vHighValue = currentMeasure.value;
                }
                else if (currentMeasure.type.label == "low"){
                    $scope.lowValue = currentMeasure.value;
                }
                else if (currentMeasure.type.label == "ehigh"){
                    $scope.eHighValue = currentMeasure.value;
                }
            }
            
            $scope.initValue = function(currentMeasure){
                if (currentMeasure.type.label == "high"){
                    currentMeasure.highval = currentMeasure.value;
                }
                else if (currentMeasure.type.label == "mid"){
                    currentMeasure.midval = currentMeasure.value;
                }
                else if (currentMeasure.type.label == "vhigh"){
                    currentMeasure.vhighval = currentMeasure.value;
                }
                else if (currentMeasure.type.label == "low"){
                    currentMeasure.lowval = currentMeasure.value;
                }
                else if (currentMeasure.type.label == "ehigh"){
                    currentMeasure.ehighval = currentMeasure.value;
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        input {
            width: 60px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="filterController">
        <div ng-repeat="x in family[0].measures" ng-init="initValue(x)">
            <p>{{x.type.measureType}}</p>
            High
            <input type="text" ng-model="x.highval"/> Mid
            <input type="text" ng-model="x.midval"/> VHigh
            <input type="text" ng-model="x.vhighval"/> Low
            <input type="text" ng-model="x.lowval"/> EHigh
            <input type="text" ng-model="x.ehighval"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```